# Создание эффекта печатной машинки

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.

Недавно я решил вернуться к обучению С++, но так как уровень моих знаний катастрофически низок, я снова пришел сюда :) Сегодня хочу попробовать сделать что-то вроде печатной машинки. Звучит громко, но объясню в чём суть. Консольное приложение на С++. Пользователь вводит свой текст, а после этого поле очищается и компьютер начинает печатать текст с интервалом в четверть (к примеру) секунды между символами.

Так как пришел я сюда, чтоб учиться, попробую высказать свои идеи. Из того, что я знаю, тут нужен Sleep, скорее всего использование массивов и циклов. Вроде как это должно быть несложно. В голове у меня промелькнула идея о том, что каждый символ из текста должен вноситься в массив. Или заменять переменную. То есть символом текста каждый раз заменяется значение переменной, а с интервалом в четверть секунды оно выводится на экран, пока есть символы во введенном тексте.

Буду благодарен тем, кто поможет немного разобраться, а лучше подтолкнет к решению.

**UPDATE**

```
 #include <iostream>

#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char string str[];
    cout << "Type your text";
    cin >> str;
    for (int i = 0; i<=str.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        cout << str[i];
        Sleep(200);
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Вот что вышло у меня. Это выдает ошибки. Что здесь неправильно?

Comment: сохраняйте строку и посимвольно печатайте ее (самый обычный перебор), в цикл вставьте sleep на 0.25сек. и все)

Comment: На будущее - если программа "выдает ошибки" - обязательно пишите, какие. Это в разы ускорит решение и уменьшит конентрацию мата)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
char string str[];
```

напишите просто

```
string str;
```

А вместо

```
str.Length

str.length()
```

Перед дальнейшими вопросами рекомендую почитать [этот ресурс](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).

Comment: К сожалению, до сих пор ошибка

Comment: @Vendetta8247, Вы пишите 

    К сожалению, до сих пор ошибка

предполагая наличие телепатических способностей у потенциально отвечающих ?

Приведите **текст, выдаваемый компилятором** (или что на экране видите).

Comment: cplusplus.com хорош только тем, что его гоогле любит, однако, если подумать головой, то всплывет тот факт, что гоогле, возможно, авторитетно в python, javascript... но не в сях и крестах. тогда недолгий поиск приведет к альтернативному [ресурсу](http://cppreference.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за комментарии. Кроме того, что ответил avp (спасибо за ресурс) нужно было дописать ещё и `#include <string>`

Comment: Единственная проблема, которая осталась - не распознает пробел. Когда я пишу текст "Hello World!" доходит до конца слова Hello и останавливается

Comment: @Vendetta8247, у меня MinGW g++ работает и без

    #include <string>

оператор >> для string вводит не всю строку, а очередное "слово". 

Для чтения всей строки вместо cin >> str; напишите

    getline(cin,str);

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str;
    cout << "Enter the String: " << endl;
    getline(cin, str);

    for (int i = 0; i <= str.length() - 1; i++)
    {
        cout << str[i];
        Sleep(200);
    }
cout << endl;
system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Вот так выглядит. Я тоже ради интереса решил сделать. То, что нужно =)

Comment: А зачем include conio.h? что это такое и нужно ли оно?

Comment: @Vendetta8247 ,чтобы использовать Sleep() нужно подключить библтотеку <conio>

Comment: @Vendetta8247 чтобы использовать функцию Sleep() нужны дополнительные 2 библиотеки: conio.h и windows.h

Comment: Для Sleep() **достаточно windows.h**. 

Без conio.h эта программа тоже отлично собирается.

--

Да вы посмотрите файл (conio.h)

     * Low level console I/O functions. Pretty please try to use the ANSI
     * standard ones if you are writing new code.

Он нужен при вызове функций getch(), kbhit() и т.п.

Answer (score -2):

Это же легко, вот тебе на C# вариант:

```
static void Main(string[]args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введите строку");
    string str = Console.ReadLine();          // считываем строку
    for (int i = 0; i <= str.Length - 1; i++) // запускаем цикл до тех пор, пока не будет достигнут последний символ нашей строки
    {
        Console.Write(str[i]);    // выводим 1 символ, с каждой итерацией он возрастает, и выводится следующая буква
        Thread.Sleep(300);        // засыпаем на 0.3 секунды.
    }
    Console.Read();               // ждем нажатия клавиши
}
```

Comment: @johniek_comp, совершенно очевидно, что у ТС проблемы **не с алгоритмом вывода**, а с **языком С++**.

Зачем ему код на *другом* языке ?